# Error inflating class on custom CheckBoxPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, custom-controls, layout-inflater, checkboxpreference

I created a custom `CheckBoxPreference` class to prevent the `CheckBoxPreference` from being clicked when the user clicks on anything else than the CheckBox itself.

It worked perfectly yesterday before leaving but for a strange reason it doesn't work today. The app crashes and i get this error :

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth, PID: 19543
>                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth/ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth.AppPreferenceActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error
>   inflating class ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth.CustomCheckBoxPreference

It crashes on this line in the code :  `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);`

I'm almost sure i did not change anything to the project other than adding a Log.i line to my main activity this morning. I tried to comment this line. Clean the project cache. Refresh Gradle projects. A google search returned me many results on **Error inflating class** and i think there's as many solutions as there's questions asked. It looks like a very generic error.

If i replace my custom `CheckBoxPreference` in the `preferences.xml` file by a normal one it works. If i put breakpoints in the class of my custom `CheckBoxPreference` it doesn't break on them. Looks like the code of the class is never executed. I'm totally lost as i'm 100% positive it was working yesterday.

Here's the custom `CheckBoxPreference` class i did :

```
package ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth;

import android.content.Context;
import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomCheckBoxPreference extends CheckBoxPreference {
    private CheckBoxPreference clickedCheckBoxPreference;

    CustomCheckBoxPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    CustomCheckBoxPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    CustomCheckBoxPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    CustomCheckBoxPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindView(View view) {
        super.onBindView(view);

        clickedCheckBoxPreference = this;

        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(android.R.id.checkbox);
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.title);

        title.setSingleLine(false);

        view.setOnClickListener(null);
        title.setOnClickListener(null);

        checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox clickedCheckBox = (CheckBox) v;

                if (clickedCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                    clickedCheckBoxPreference.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    clickedCheckBoxPreference.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here's the `preferences.xml` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:sbp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth">

    <EditTextPreference
            android:title="@string/url_title"
            android:key="url"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_url"

    />
    <EditTextPreference
            android:title="@string/pwd_title"
            android:key="pwd"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_pwd"

    />
    <ListPreference
            android:title="@string/orientation_title"
            android:key="orientation"
            android:entries="@array/orientation_display"
            android:entryValues="@array/orientation_values"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_orientation"
    />
    <ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth.CustomCheckBoxPreference
        android:title="@string/progress_title"
        android:key="progress"
        android:defaultValue="@string/app_progress"
    />
    <ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth.CustomCheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/js_title"
            android:key="js"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_js"
    />
    <ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth.CustomCheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/tts_title"
            android:key="tts"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_tts"
    />
    <ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth.CustomCheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/clear_cache_title"
            android:key="clear_cache"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_clear_cache"
            android:disableDependentsState="true"
    />
    <ListPreference
            android:title="@string/cache_mode_title"
            android:key="cache_mode"
            android:entries="@array/cache_mode_display"
            android:entryValues="@array/cache_mode_values"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_cache_mode"
            android:dependency="clear_cache"
    />
    <ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth.CustomCheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/clear_history_title"
            android:key="clear_history"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_clear_history"
    />
    <ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth.CustomCheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/clear_form_title"
            android:key="clear_form"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_clear_form"
    />
    <ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth.CustomCheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/keep_alive_title"
            android:key="keep_alive"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_keep_alive"
    />
    <ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth.CustomCheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/viewport_title"
            android:key="viewport"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_viewport"
    />
    <ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth.CustomCheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/fit_title"
            android:key="fit"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_fit"
            android:dependency="viewport"
    />
    <ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth.CustomCheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/zoom_support_title"
            android:key="zoom_support"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_zoom_support"
    />
    <ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth.CustomCheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/zoom_controls_title"
            android:key="zoom_controls"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_zoom_controls"
            android:dependency="zoom_support"
    />
    <ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth.SeekBarPreference
            android:key="zoom_default"
            android:title="@string/zoom_default_title"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_zoom_default"
            sbp:maxValue="100"
    />
    <ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth.CustomCheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/error_back_btn_title"
            android:key="error_back_btn"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_error_back_btn"
    />
    <ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth.CustomCheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/error_home_btn_title"
            android:key="error_home_btn"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_error_home_btn"
    />
    <ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth.CustomCheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/restrict_host_title"
            android:key="restrict_host"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_restrict_host"
    />
    <ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth.CustomCheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/debug_info_title"
            android:key="debug_info"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_debug_info"
    />
    <ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth.CustomCheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/autocomplete_title"
            android:key="autocomplete"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_autocomplete"
    />
    <ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth.CustomCheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/adjust_height_title"
            android:key="adjust_height"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_adjust_height"
    />
    <ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth.SeekBarPreference
            android:key="adjust_tolerance"
            android:title="@string/adjust_tolerance_title"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_adjust_tolerance"
            android:dependency="adjust_height"
            sbp:maxValue="100"
    />
    <ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth.CustomCheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/long_click_title"
            android:key="long_click"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_long_click"
    />
    <ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth.SeekBarPreference
            android:key="settings_delay"
            android:title="@string/settings_delay_title"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_settings_delay"
            sbp:maxValue="5"
    />
    <ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth.SeekBarPreference
            android:key="settings_nb_touch"
            android:title="@string/settings_nb_touch_title"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_settings_nb_touch"
            sbp:maxValue="10"
    />
    <ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth.CustomCheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/file_access_title"
            android:key="file_access"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_file_access"
    />
    <ListPreference
            android:title="@string/js_file_access_title"
            android:key="js_file_access"
            android:entries="@array/js_file_access_display"
            android:entryValues="@array/js_file_access_values"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_js_file_access"
    />
    <ca.qc.gouv.stat.kth.CustomCheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/content_url_access_title"
            android:key="content_url_access"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_content_url_access"
    />
    <ListPreference
            android:title="@string/mixed_content_title"
            android:key="mixed_content"
            android:entries="@array/mixed_content_display"
            android:entryValues="@array/mixed_content_values"
            android:defaultValue="@string/app_mixed_content"
    />
    <Preference
            android:title="@string/exit_btn_lbl"
            android:key="exit"
    />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Targeting api 26, min api 21;

Comment: Please read this before post a question :: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  :: You should post your code here on SO not on an external site.

Answer (score 1):

Well after 3 hours of research i found the solution right after posting this question ...

It's because i did not declare the constructors as public. By default they are package protected and since the api calls them on `addPreferencesFromResource` it fails. It's strange cause i'm sure yesterday it was working and my constructors were not declared public. Anyway it works now and i know why so i'll move on.